# Getting error while importing CSV file to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am trying to import a CSV file to Data extension (by using import option), but getting the invalid field error.

This was worked previously, but now it is failing. Could you please help me to figure out the issue?

**My Data Extension**

[image: Data Extension details]

**My CSV file**

```
Id,Email Address
1,testuser@gmail.com
```

[image: csv file]

I am getting the below error while importing the csv.
[image: Error details]

Recently we migrated our programs to Automation Studio. Is there any relation with Automation Studio and this error?

Comment: What delimiter is configured in your import definition?

Comment: Is it because your DE column name is Emailaddress and the column name in the .csv is Email Address?

Answer (score 1):

Appears your delimiter has changed in your test file or the import is expecting a pipe delimiter.

I'm curious why you have the Emailaddress column in your Data Extension set to `Text (100)` instead of the `EmailAddress` data type.